# Why do dots ("." and "..") appear when I print files from directory?

Tags: c, directory, printf, readdir

I'm printing files from two directories using C language. Here is my code:

```
char *list1[30], *list2[30];
int i=0, x=0;
struct dirent *ent, *ent1;

/* print all the files and directories within directory */
    while ((ent = readdir (dirSource)) != NULL) {
        list1[i] = ent->d_name; 
        i++;        
    }
    i=0;
    while((ent1 = readdir (dirDest)) != NULL) {
        list2[i] = ent1->d_name;    
        i++;
    }

    while(x != i){
        printf("Daemon - %s\n", list1[x]);
        printf("Daemon1 - %s\n", list2[x]);
        x++;
    }
```

I can print all the files, but everytime I print the files in a directory, the end result is this:

Daemon - .
Daemon1 - .
Daemon - ..
Daemon1 - ..
Daemon - fich5
Daemon1 - fich4
Daemon - fich3
Daemon1 - fich3

I don't understand why there are dots in the beginning.
Obs.: I don't if it matters, but I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 on a pen, meaning every time I use Ubuntu, I use the trial instead of using dual boot on my pc.

Comment: Are those pointers even valid?

Answer (score 4):

`.` and `..` are two special files which are in every directory in Linux and other Unix-like systems. `.` represents the current directory and `..` represents the parent directory.

Comment: I'm sure Windows likes those dots too, even if it is not very unix-like.

Answer (score 2):

Every directory in Unix has the entry `.` (meaning current directory) and `..` (the parent directory). 
Give that they start  with "." they are hidden files; `ls` normally do not show them unless you use "-a" option.

See:

```
[:~/tmp/lilla/uff] % ls -l
total 0
-rw-rw-r-- 1 romano romano 0 May 17 18:48 a
-rw-rw-r-- 1 romano romano 0 May 17 18:48 b
[:~/tmp/lilla/uff] % ls -la
total 8
drwxrwxr-x 2 romano romano 4096 May 17 18:48 .
drwxrwxr-x 3 romano romano 4096 May 17 18:47 ..
-rw-rw-r-- 1 romano romano    0 May 17 18:48 a
-rw-rw-r-- 1 romano romano    0 May 17 18:48 b
```